# Eclipse - Show more than 100 warnings in Problems tab

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

In Eclipse (2018-09) Problems tab, I have thousands of warnings, but it display only 100 warnings,

I follow [blog](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2009/08/26/how-to-get-eclipse-to-show-more-than-100-errorswarnings/) suggestion:

> In your Eclipse IDE Preferences (whether its Eclipse, Flex Builder or Adobe ColdFusion Builder), any Eclipse based IDE, you will find this setting under Java->Compiler->Building.

[image]

But I still see only 100 warnings after `clean` projects and restart

-Note I found in comments workaround, but I don't see such option in my eclipse:

> Click corner triangle.
>   Select preferences
>
> Uncross:
>   [ ] Use marker limits

Is there a way to display all compiler warnings in eclipse?

Comment: That option refers to the Problems or Markers views themselves.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I changed the limit,but still I can see only 100 warnings

Comment: Keep reading. There are more answers below the accepted answer which show you what to do for more recent versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This applies to eclipse neon, on problems view click on triangle pointing down on top-right corner. Then select "Configure Contents...". Under "Number of items visible per group" enter the value what you want.

Comment: It works when I click on Filters (not Configure Contents)